# If values are the same update code

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

http://liveweave.com/R9jW9x

I have 4 textbox's each representing a css padding location (ex. padding-top, padding-left, etc:)

I'm experimenting with value detections. What I'm trying to figure out is when padding top and bottom `[A]` are the same values (as well as left and right `[B]`) how to set the values to `padding: A B`;

If all are same to set value to `padding: A;`
If all are different set value to nothing/blank
and
If all are different, or A & B maybe same, but C and D maybe different then to set value to `padding: A B C D;`

The script works fine onload, but when the input values are changed my result is not finalizing.

Can anybody explain why this is?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var top = $(".padding-top").val(),
      bottom = $(".padding-bottom").val(),
      left = $(".padding-left").val(),
      right = $(".padding-right").val(),
      result = $(".padding-final");

  // Update padding code
  var Finalize = function() {
    if ((top === "") && (right === "") && (bottom === "") && (left === "")) {
      // Check if all are empty
      result.val("");
    } else if ((top === right) && (bottom === left)) {
      // If all are same
      result.val("padding: " + top + "px;");
    } else if ((top === bottom) && (left === right)) {
      // Check if first two values are same
      result.val("padding: " + top + "px " + left + "px;");
    } else {
      result.val("padding: " + top + "px " + right + "px " + bottom + "px " + left + "px;");
    }
  };

  // Update padding code when sides change
  $(window).on('load keyup change', function() {
    Finalize();
  });
});
```

Comment: Just updated my answer with code. You may want to look at it for an idea on how to finish this problem.

Comment: Gracias I understand the process much better now. My current problem seems to reside where the script is not calling upon onchange. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't write the code for you. But, I will hopefully send you in the right direction:

First, you should check whether padding-top, padding-right, padding-bottom, and padding-left are equal to each other.

>> If they are equal, then you can set the middle one equal to any of the values (since they're equal).

>> If they are not equal, then you can check to see if top and bottom are equal to each other && left and right are equal to each other. If they are, then you can set the middle to the top/bottom number + " " + left/right number.

>> Else set the middle to top number, right number, bottom number, left number.

---

**EDIT**

Actually, I got to tinkering a bit with the idea and came up with this to help you a bit more. But, that's it. No more help from me!

```
var top = 2;
var bottom = 2;
var right = 5;
var left = 5;

top == bottom && right == left && top == left ? alert(top) 
    : top == bottom && right == left ? alert(top + " " + left) 
        : alert(top + " " + right + " " + bottom + " " + left);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/senju/52yquq3y/)

---

After you solve this, a more challenging problem would be to type numbers into the middle box and change the top/right/bottom/left paddings accordingly.

Comment: I figured out why my values where's updating. I didn't put my variables into my function where the values where changing lol

Answer (score 0):

I would play with this

```
var a=$(".padding-top"), b=..., c=..., d=...;
var test=0,padding;
if (a)                 test += 1;
if (b&& b!=a)          test += 2;
if (c && c!=a)         test += 4;
if (d && d!=c && d!=a) test += 8;

if (test== 1) padding = a;
if (test== 2 || test == 3) padding = a + " " + b;  // when a+b or just b, we need a and b
if (test>4 && test < 8) padding = a + " " + b + " " + c; // c, a+c or b+c
if (test > 8) padding = a + " " + b + " " + c " " + d;
```

Also you can do

```
$(".paddings").on('keyup change', function() {
  Finalize();
});
```

and use IDs for padding-top, left, bottom, right

Comment: Can you provide some explanation about this approach?

Comment: give each padding a unique (binary) number so when added together you can immediately see 1001 is a and d, 1100 is a, b and so on. I did not do it exactly the way I wanted, but posted it anyway

Answer (score 0):

As stated cases in your question, i have made following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var top = $(".padding-top").val(),
        bottom = $(".padding-bottom").val(),
        left = $(".padding-left").val(),
        right = $(".padding-right").val(),
        result = 'Padding: ';
      // Applies new code value
      function Finalize() {
        if(top === bottom === left === right) {
            //If all are same
            result +=  top + ' ';
        } else {
            if ((top === bottom) && (left === right)) {
              // Check if first two values are same
                result +=  top + ' ' + left + ' ';
            } else {
                result +=  left + ' ' + right + ' ' + top + ' ' + bottom + ' ';
            }
        }
        result += 'Px';
        $('#middle-input').val(result);
      }

      Finalize();
      $(".padding-inputs").on('keyup change', function() {
        Finalize();
      });
});
```